# Question closure: inconsistency?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This came up just a couple of days ago on [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29865/how-can-i-find-like-minded-musicians-of-similar-skill-to-collaborate-with).  Commenters seemed to side on the side of not closing it, but it was closed, citing that listing ways for musicians to find other musicians was a list of resources.

Yet [this topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/finding-bandmates-in-a-new-city), which is basically the same question, but without the word "online", was allowed without issue.  The answers were simply *answers*, not *resources*.

Why close one and not the other; what is the difference?

Comment: Judging from the edits you made to your closed question, I think you are aware of the differences.

Comment: If you look at my last comment I made I said I was going to edit the question, because a comment was made that an edit might reopen it.  I assumed that whoever I was asking here in meta would be looking at both versions (can't they see everything?).

Comment: You asked "what is the difference"? Based on your edits, you know the difference. It's all I'm saying.

Comment: Incorrect.  I am asking what is the difference in the two topics by the person who closed the thread (who commented regarding reopening it and editing it) and by people who can close threads.  The original title was "What are _online_ ways to find like-minded musicians to collaborate with."  It's all in the comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I insist, that difference is the same you found and corrected by editing. If you are interested in the opinion of the mod that closed it exclusively, he already answered that question in the comments, which you already knew about. You know the difference by both your and his (the closer) rationale.

Comment: Before and after the edit, I can't see any answers to your question being anything but links and a short review which is based on the opinion of the user that answers. Because of this it will result in any and every answer being equally valid and not really good for a Q&A site. If you can make your question more _objective_, I can see it working. Also if you want a general idea you can ask pretty much anything in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) even if it's not a good fit for the main portion of the site.

Answer (score 6):

First off, those two questions are entirely different. They are not "basically the same question" - the first one is completely off-topic, as described by @MatthewRead and will generate list answers.

The second one asks how to find bandmates and in fact has been answered very well without any list of resources.

It's that whole 'give a man a fish' and 'teach a man to fish' difference.

But in any case, what it comes down to is people. The community decides what is or isn't on topic. If this changes over time, we can update the Scope as written. Mods work to the community mandate, ie enough flags, or a post that is explicitly outside our scope will be closed. Conversely, if a mod closes a post and the community disagrees, we reopen.